# How inject DataSource(HikariCP) in Auto Configuration class?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, hikaricp

I'm trying to use `Spring Boot 2 + Spring Data + Custom Auto Configuration Classes` but for some reason can't inject `DataSource`(provided by HikariCP) in the third class.

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class InitialAutoConfiguration {
 //Beans to load in theory first.
}


@Configuration
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@AutoConfigureAfter(InitialAutoConfiguration.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = Asset.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = AssetRepository.class,
    repositoryBaseClass = BaseRepositoryImpl.class,
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = ExtendedJpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class JpaAutoConfiguration { //Load Jpa Classes
}


@Configuration
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@AutoConfigureAfter(JpaAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxx"})
public class ServiceConfiguration {
    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource; //Datasource is null

    @Bean
    public DbPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer dbPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    DbPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer = new DbPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(dataSource);
    placeholderConfigurer.setPlaceholderPrefix("%{");
    placeholderConfigurer.setPlaceholderSuffix("}");
    return placeholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

`META-INF/spring.factories`

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.xetec.autoconfigure.InitialAutoConfiguration,\
  com.xetec.autoconfigure.JpaAutoConfiguration,\
  com.xetec.autoconfigure.ServiceConfiguration
```

Looks like my classes are loading before the Spring Data Classes(`DataSourceAutoConfiguration.Hikari`).

Is there one way to first load the Spring Boot Starters Classes then after my custom ones please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am no sure if the following change can solve your issue, but i meet with the similar problem

add **static** in your method

```
@Bean
    public static DbPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer dbPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of highest and lowest precedence is the wrong way round. Your `ServiceConfiguration` is ordered with highest precedence which means that it will be evaluated first.

Rather than using absolute ordering, I would use `@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)`

Comment: Hi @Andy tried to use `@AutoConfigureAfter(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class), @DependsOn("dataSource")` and in spring.factories `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration` but all didn't work, the DataSource is always null. When used `@DependsOn` the method in  `DataSourceConfiguration.Hikari.dataSource` is called but the DatasourceProperties is not binded then throw exception `DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class`.

Comment: You shouldn’t be listing Boot’s own auto-configuration in your spring.factories. It’s already listed in its own file.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson if DbPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is a BeanFactoryPostProcessor, this bean creation method will cause ServiceConfiguration instantiation very early, so DataSource is null at that time

Comment: Good point, @clevertension. I'd overlooked that `DbPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` was, presumably, a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. Injecting anything into a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is to be avoided as it will be required very early in the application context's lifecycle.